# Monggose/Angular/Node: route with deleteOne method keeps saying object is deleted but the deletecount is zero

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, mean-stack

I've seen other posts with this issuel, but I could not adapt their solutions to my problem: I have a small MEAN app using mongoose. The issue occurs when I try to delete a user or other object stored in the collection. The route works fine, I get no errors, but the objects dont get deleted and I dont understand. I've reinstalled mongoose over and over, tried other methods, like `findByIdAndDelete` but nothing...Can someone helpe solve this?
Here is there relevant code:

Model file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    index:true,
    required: true
  },
  rate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

Model Route:

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Movie.deleteOne({
    _id: req.params._id
  }).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Movie deleted!",
      movie:result
    });
  });
});
```

Movie Service (angular)

```
deleteMovie(id:any){
  return this.http.delete(baseUrl + 'movie/' + id)
}
```

Movie component.ts

```
deleteMovie(id){

  this.movieService.deleteMovie(id).subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.movieService.getStoredMovies();
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul *ngFor="let movie of storedMovies | unique; let i=index">
              <li *ngIf="i<=10 " (click)="deleteMovie(movie)">
                {{movie.name}}
              </li>
            </ul>
```

**Message from backend after deletion:**

[image]

**Log of a get object method**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your `Model Route` specifically at `_id: req.params._id`.

According to your route

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res, next) => { })
```

You are receiving `id` not `_id`

So you have to get `id` from params like this  `_id: req.params.id`.

Your end result would look like this

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Movie.deleteOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  }).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Movie deleted!",
      movie:result
    });
  });
});
```

**Update**

I also looked at your `HTML` and found that you are passing whole `movie` object on `(click)`. But `deleteMovie(id)` only wants `id`, so you have to update your HTML like this

```
<ul *ngFor="let movie of storedMovies | unique; let i=index">
              <li *ngIf="i<=10 " (click)="deleteMovie(movie._id)">
                {{movie.name}}
              </li>
            </ul>
```